# Use vba to refresh & renew table links

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have designed a system that is used to track customer activity and log calls to a department. The front end and back end database are written in access. This system is due to go to the USA division of the company i work for.

The front end needs to automatically refresh the tables and if the backend database has moved (which it will when i send it to the US) the code will then look at a function to read the location of the new database. Sample of the read text file function code shown below:

```
    Function ReadDbPassword()

'--
' Filetostring(FILEInput$ as variant) ' to make this a callable function
Dim FILEInput As Variant
'--

On Error GoTo FileToString_Error

FILEInput = "C:\Users\Public\databaseUser\PassCon"
Passmyfile = FreeFile
Open FILEInput For Input As Passmyfile

Passthedata4 = Input(LOF(Passmyfile), Passmyfile)
Close Passmyfile

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

FileToString_Error:

MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")"
```

End Function

The text file contains a path like the one below:

P:\Projects\Database.accdb

I have found code that uses a similar idea to what i want and i have been looking at the code on the link below, however i do not fully understand how this code works in order to alter it to what I need to use the read text file.

http:/ /access.mvps.org/access/tables/tbl0009.htm

-------EDIT --------
I have tried to edit the following section to use the read text function

```
Function fGetMDBName(strIn As String) As String
'Calls GetOpenFileName dialog
Dim strFilter As String

    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, _
                    "Access Database(*.mdb;*.mda;*.mde;*.mdw) ", _
                    "*.mdb; *.mda; *.mde; *.mdw")
    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, _
                    "All Files (*.*)", _
                    "*.*")

    fGetMDBName = ahtCommonFileOpenSave(Filter:=strFilter, _
                                OpenFile:=True, _
                                DialogTitle:=strIn, _
                                Flags:=ahtOFN_HIDEREADONLY)
End Function
```

By replacing all the code with 
fGetMDBName = Passmyfile

Comment: What is the part you don't understand?  What have you tried?

Comment: Please see the section labelled Edit. I can follow the code to refresh the links, after that when it starts to look for a new data source i get lost and cant understand how its attempting to load the tables from the new source.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing apples and oranges in what you are trying to do. Here are my suggestions:

1. Make sure your module has 'Option Explicit' then compile all your code. I see variables referenced but have no idea what TYPE they are.
2. Change your Function 'ReadDbPassword()' to return a string variable, then set it to return Passthedata4.
3. The second Function you listed (fGetMDBName) is opening a File Dialog box to allow you to select a file name. You do not need that since you already will have the file path/name from your first Function.
4. Then adapt the code you found that does the relink to use the path/name from your subroutine.